# How to setup Magento in DMZ? need help!

Tags: setup

Lets consider machine with **IP:192.168.1.60 is in DMZ with NAT IP:111.222.333.444.** 
How should i configure the baseURL in database so that public users can access the site as well as i should be able to view the site when entered "http://localhost/"

**Case 1:** If I enter public IP URL **eg:"111.222.333.444/test**
in database baseURL,then URL localhost/test doesnt work on the machine as it in DMZ and no internet access and browser is trying to connect public ip from local machine.

But URL is accessable from public users.

**Case 2:** If I enter intranet IP as a URL **"http://192.168.1.60/test** in baseURL then public users cant access the site as the database baseURL is pointing out to intranet ip.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have a single domain name specified as you Base URL. If you want to access the website in your intranet thru an internal IP I would suggest you use a internal DNS server to point the same domain to the internal IP.

For example:
External DNS entry (in public nameserver):
mywebsite.com A 111.222.333.444

In your internal DNS Server (only used by clients on you Intranet):
mywebsite.com A 192.168.1.60

Now you can configure the Base URL with http://mywebsite.com/ making it accessable to both networks